# Can't install grub-customizer on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, grub2, kubuntu, 22.04

I upgraded from Kubuntu 21.10 to Kubuntu 22.04, but grub-customizer got removed. I want to reinstall it, but apt doesn't find the package. Also, I read in [an article](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/jammy/universe/base/grub-customizer) that the latest version is `*DELETED*`. So, is it still available in the Ubuntu repos? If it isn't: Will it be available again?

Comment: Now uses grub  2.06. Typically grub-customizer backed up all the grub scripts and replaced then with proxy files. So probably not updated, yet for 2.06.  What is it you want to change? Often not difficult to manually edit grub configuration files, if willing to manually  edit files.

Comment: I want to change/delete some unnecessary entries.

Comment: In UEFI settings with efibootmgr or in grub menu. I like to turn off os-prober which may be default now & put only the entries I want into 40_custom. If some other entries created by the scripts, you can change script to not be executable. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus  How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen